# Unable to select files on Mobile both IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I'm trying to be able to upload an image to change a background of a table automatically, but it is only working on Desktop computers, it won’t work on neither IOS nor Android, anyone has any pointers? Thanks in advance.

```
const frame = document.getElementById('table');
const file = document.getElementById('file');
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
  frame.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ reader.result })`;
}, false);
file.addEventListener('change',function() {
  const image = this.files[0];
  if(image) reader.readAsDataURL(image);
}, false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using object urls

```js
document.body.id = 'table'

const [{style}, file] = document.querySelectorAll('#table, #file')

file.addEventListener('change', img => {
  [img] = file.files
  style.backgroundImage = img ? `url(${URL.createObjectURL(img)})` : ''
})
```

```html
<input type=file id=file accept="image/*">
```

Comment: That is so cool thanks so much the querySelectorAll is nice too thanks I did not know of it existence :)

Comment: `querySelector()` will match any first given selector based on css queries, `querySelectorAll()` will find all items